# 12.04 upgrade broke grub? (not wubi related)

Tags: 12.04, grub2, updates

I just updated from 11.10 to 12.04, with no major problems (it took a while to get past a request to restart ssh, mysql and some other services, but I did no fiddling by myself, everything was done by the installer). However, after restarting, grub can't do anything. Picking the new linux installation (first entry), I just get

```
error: no such partition
error: no such partition
error: no such partition
```

and picking the recovery-version just gives 5 lines instead of 3.
 I have windows 7 installed on a different drive, and can run it by booting from that drive instead. Picking it from the grub menu gives the same error as above (can't remember how many lines, though). I'll be honest and say that I don't remember if win 7 could be booted from grub before the update, though.
In short, nothing on the grub menu works.

any solutions? The grub menu changed appearance - before it was on a purple background, small letters, now it's white-on-black, big letters, looking very basic.

The original installation was from a usb-drive, and I hadn't heard about wubi until I started googling this problem, so I doubt there's any connection.

I really hope there are some grub-savvy people out there :)

---

### EDIT:

ok. so, I made a bootable usb, and am running from that right now. when I ran the bootinfoscript, it warned me that

```
 "gawk" could not be found, using "busybox awk" instead.
This may lead to unreliable results.
```

just so you know.

The contents of RESULTS.txt are:

---

```
              Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]
```

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

```
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos3)/boot/grub on this drive.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.
```

sda1: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  Dell Utility: FAT16
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /DELLBIO.BIN /DELLRMK.BIN /COMMAND.COM
```

sda2: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sda3: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows 7
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sda4: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  Windows 7: FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows XP
Boot files:        /boot.ini /bootmgr /ntldr /NTDETECT.COM
```

sdb1: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sdb2: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sdb3: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99)
Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sdb3 
                   and looks at sector 375893584 of the same hard drive 
                   for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                   for (,msdos3)/boot/grub on this drive.
Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img
```

sdb4: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sdc1: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.06 4.06-pre1
Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 4649656 of /dev/sdc1 for its 
                   second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the  directory. 
                   The integrity check of the ADV area failed. No errors 
                   found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux/syslinux.cfg /ldlinux.sys
```

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                  63       240,974       240,912  de Dell Utility
/dev/sda2             241,664    21,213,183    20,971,520   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3    *     21,213,184   483,151,863   461,938,680   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4         483,151,872   488,394,751     5,242,880   f W95 Extended (LBA)
/dev/sda5         483,153,920   488,394,751     5,240,832  dd Dell Media Direct
```

Drive: sdb ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                  63   345,886,749   345,886,687   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sdb2         345,888,768   361,510,911    15,622,144  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3    *    361,510,912   390,807,786    29,296,875  83 Linux
/dev/sdb4         390,809,600   488,394,751    97,585,152  83 Linux
```

Drive: sdc ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 8015 MB, 8015282176 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 974 cylinders, total 15654848 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1    *          2,048    15,652,863    15,650,816   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
```

"blkid" output: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        07D8-0411                              vfat       DellUtility
/dev/sda2        E2765BBC765B9061                       ntfs       RECOVERY
/dev/sda3        98DC5E54DC5E2D2E                       ntfs       OS
/dev/sda5        7061-9DF5                              vfat       MEDIADIRECT
/dev/sdb1        01CBBB4C3374C3B0                       ntfs       Data1
/dev/sdb2        1ca45f3f-f888-43d1-8137-02699597189a   swap       
/dev/sdb3        6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e   ext4       
/dev/sdb4        58e2b257-8608-4b11-b20b-dc162bb80b62   ext4       
/dev/sdc1        0C02B64402B63316                       ntfs       PENDRIVE
```

================================ Mount points: =================================

```
Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb4        /media/58e2b257-8608-4b11-b20b-dc162bb80b62 ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
/dev/sdc1        /cdrom                   fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

================================ sda5/boot.ini: ================================

---

```
[boot loader]
timeout=0
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Embedded" /fastdetect /KERNEL=NTOSBOOT.EXE /maxmem=1024
```

---

=========================== sdb3/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd1,msdos3)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd1,msdos3)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="$1"
    if [ "$1" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ ${recordfail} != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "$linux_gfx_mode" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-24-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-19-generic root=UUID=6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-19-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-19-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.0.0-19-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-19-generic root=UUID=6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-19-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 98DC5E54DC5E2D2E
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Microsoft Windows XP Embedded (on /dev/sda5)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod fat
    set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7061-9DF5
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

---

=============================== sdb3/etc/fstab: ================================

---

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=6bc1b599-ad4b-403c-a155-a5bc81211f5e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=58e2b257-8608-4b11-b20b-dc162bb80b62 /home           ext4    defaults,user_xattr        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=1ca45f3f-f888-43d1-8137-02699597189a none            swap    sw              0       0
```

---

=================== sdb3: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

```
       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

           =                boot/grub/core.img                             1
           =                boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
           =                boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-19-generic               2
           =                boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic               2
           =                boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-19-generic                  2
           =                boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic                  1
           =                vmlinuz                                        1
           =                vmlinuz.old                                    2
```

=========================== sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

---

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

---

========================= sdc1/syslinux/syslinux.cfg: ==========================

---

```
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50

# If you would like to use the new menu and be presented with the option to install or run from USB at startup, remove # from the following line. This line was commented out (by request of many) to allow the old menu to be presented and to enable booting straight into the Live Environment! 
# ui gfxboot bootlogo
```

---

=================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

```
       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

        ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             0
```

================= sdc1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

```
       GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

        ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1
        ?? = ??             syslinux/chain.c32                             1
        ?? = ??             syslinux/gfxboot.c32                           1
        ?? = ??             syslinux/syslinux.cfg                          0
        ?? = ??             syslinux/vesamenu.c32                          1
```

============== sdc1: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux: ===============

```
 syslinux/chain.c32                 :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
 syslinux/gfxboot.c32               :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
 syslinux/vesamenu.c32              :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
```

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

```
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
./bootinfoscript: line 1646: [: 2.73495e+09: integer expression expected
```

---

Comment: Please run Boot Info Script and post the RESULTS.txt which it produces. http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/

Comment: how? it seems I need a working linux installation to do that?

Comment: To discover what is going wrong, when you get the menu press the c key and enter the `ls`, `set`,  and `lsmod` commands. Please tell us the prompt you get, and the output of the above. As a general "just fix it" response, @jP_wanN's answer to boot your Ubuntu and reinstall grub is a good idea. Booting grub from second disks can be complicated because BIOS's idea of drive identity might not match that of the installing system's. It can be better to install a small grub partition on your first disk. Your bootinfo information looks good to me except for the grub module location list.

Answer (score 1):

Burn a [Super Grub2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/), and use it to boot into Ubuntu. Then again execute the bootinfoscript (not necessary, only to make sure the /dev-Names didn't change). Check if

```
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
for (,msdos3)/boot/grub on this drive.
```

changed (the important part is *in the MBR of* **...**). If so, you'll have to adjust the follwing command (for example **/dev/sdc** instead of **/dev/sdb**), else you just execute it from any terminal:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```